# Python PuLP "Overwriting previously set objective." and __dummy = None

Tags: python, warnings, pulp

I have built a pretty complex MIP in Python `PuLP`. Obviously a bit too complex for me. When I run it it gives the following Warning:

> UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective.
>   warnings.warn("Overwriting previously set objective.")

The problem performs some calculations but does not come to the expected solution.

The `LpStatus[prob.status]` returns `Optimal`

The `prob.objective` returns `None`

When I print the `prob.variables()` with

```
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

I get `__dummy = None` in between the other variables.

Can anyone explain what the `__dummy = None` means in this context? Where could I look for a solution? I was pretty sure that I have only one objective function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution. I indeed overwrote the objective function without noticing it.

Here is the piece of code that caused the warning:

```
for i in range(len(items)):
        for l in range(L):
            prob += delta[0-l] == 0
```

the delta variable is a list of lists. The first index was missing, the program therefore compared a list with a zero. Since this is not possible, the equation always returns false (maybe coded as zero) which was then interpreted as an objective function.

This solved the issue:

```
for i in range(len(items)):
        for l in range(L):
            prob += delta[i][0-l] == 0
```

Now it adds equations instead of values to the prob.

I hope this helps anyone encountering a similar problem.